# Angular: how to get the raw route path

Tags: angular

I want to track the original paths of my Angular routes, without any actual IDs and other params in the URL.

So for a given component, instead of getting `pets/123/edit` as URL, I want to receive `pets/:petId/edit` as a String, so I can put it in my analytics tool.

I could not find any way how to get the raw path, but only the actual URLs including IDs and such.

Answer (score 1):

Together with some magic and inspiration from @Daniel's answer, this seems to work and gets me the full raw path (including multiple children layers).

This is then used in a root service. (@Injectable with providedIn=root)

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const segments: string[] = [];
    let currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = router.routerState.root.snapshot;
    while (currentRoute) {
      const path = currentRoute.routeConfig?.path;
      if (path && path !== '') { // Filter out these empty paths
        segments.push(path);
      }
      currentRoute = currentRoute.children[0];
    }
    const rawPath = segments.join('/');
    console.log(rawPath);
    // Outputs for example: pets/:petIdentifier/food/:foodIdentifier/edit

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. I think that you can make use of Angular's ActivatedRoute snapshot data.

Something like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: 'app-example.html',
  style: 'app-example.scss'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  rawPath: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rawPath = this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.path;
  }
}
```

For example, if in your routing module you had a path defined like:

```
{ path: 'pets/:petId/edit', component: PetEditComponent }
```

Then within the PetEditComponent, this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.path would return 'pets/:petId/edit'.

Comment: Hi, yeah that is part of the solution I guess. I provided an oversimplified example but my routing is built up from multiple parent/children routing configuration and this solution will only get that particular child route.

To make it even more complicated: I'm trying to use this in a root @Injectable that will listen to all routes visited in the application

Comment: I somehow figured out something that works. Check out my answer.

Comment: Y wanted to add similar example in stackblitz but it took me more then you :D 

I would go like you with navigationEnd. I try to create service with two methods and its similar to your logic.